# Testing WebAuthn via REST tool?

Tags: postman, webauthn

Is it possible to test this locally via a rest tool. I've created the backend to generate the challenge etc for Registration of new creds, but without the WebAuthn response I'm at a loss if I have created the correct way to digest the response object from WebAuthn.

Answer (score 3):

If you're writing a FIDO2 / WebAuthn library, the FIDO Alliance does actually provide with a test suite that should be capable of generating tests: [FIDO Alliance - Conformance Self‐Validation Testing](https://fidoalliance.org/certification/functional-certification/conformance/) (then clic on "registration" in the  "FIDO2 Test Tools" section).

Note that the same FIDO Alliance proposes a non-mandatory standard way of exposing FIDO2 through a REST API: [Transport Binding Profile](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-v2.0-rd-20180702/fido-server-v2.0-rd-20180702.html#transport-binding-profile)

Answer (score 2):

You can request FIDO conformance tools [here](https://fidoalliance.org/tool-request-agreement/)

I believe we will choose FIDO2 if we now start implementing FIDO

See the screenshot below
[image]

If you want some data to test with