# WebAuthn / FIDO2 Attestation Object and Client Data JSON Examples

Tags: fido-u2f, webauthn

I'm currently building a server library for WebAuthn / FIDO2 registration and authentication. What I have found is that there are a LOT of permutations of what kind of attestation objects that can be sent. I want to be sure that the tests I'm writing for the library will cover at least the most common combinations of Attestation formats with their signing keys and hashing algorithms.

In order for me to do this is there any pre-existing examples I can use as a reference?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check this answer: [Testing WebAuthn via REST tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435727/testing-webauthn-via-rest-tool)

Note that the test suite doesn't work on Linux as of June 2019.